# How to generate FullCalendar from button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

All documentation I've seen loads AR Shaws FullCalendar on Document.Ready as so....

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       // my options and callbacks here
    })

});
```

On one particular page I am offering the user the ability to select what events will be rendered by offering a set of cascading dropdowns. Only after all the dropdowns are set do I want to generate the calendar. So I have a button which will run a client script to check that the dropdowns all have values selected and if OK I then want the calendar to generate. I already have code in the options section that grabs the values of the dropdowns and uses that to get the event that match the criteria.

My button onClick code is...

```
function butGenCal() {
    // code to check dropdownlists
    // if pass then I call
    genCalendar();
    // else I show error message
}
```

My genCalendar code is...

```
function GenCalendar() {
    (function() {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          // my options and callbacks here
      })

    });
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work... no errors showing either. Any help appreciated.

Comment: It would be better if you can make a JSfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/marcrazyness/98bu7/

I think the issue in your case might be the parenthesis and extra function definition:

```
function GenCalendar() {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          // my options and callbacks here
      });
}
```

Comment: Job done... many thanks. I'm a VB person and unfortunately have major issues with anything that uses curly stuff - all these parenthesis and semi colons just mess me up :)

Comment: Totally glad I could help, I'm a java guy so I had an advantage on the js learning curve :)

Answer (score 0):

write a timeout function

```
setTimeout(function(){
              GenCalendar();
          },1000);
```